# Make Capybara's within() method find Rails' resource IDs, e.g. #user_1234?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I often have the following code in my specs:

```
  within "#user_#{@user.id}" do
    page.should have_content(@user.email)
  end
```

It would be really nice if Capybara would be able to determine the wanted ID from a given resource object, e.g.:

```
  within @user do
    page.should have_content(@user.email)
  end
```

Is there an easy way to do this? One could try to override the `find` method, but maybe there's a better way?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: would just consist in using this method: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/RecordIdentifier/dom_id

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just add `include ActionController::RecordIdentifier` to `spec/support/` (rspec/capybara) or `features/support` (cucumber/capybara)?

Then you can do things like:

```
within "##{dom_id(user)}" do
  find('button').click
end
```

**Update for Rails 4**: `include ActionView::RecordIdentifier` to avoid deprecation warning (thanks @robertwbradford)

Comment: For Rails 4 and beyond it's best to use `include ActionView::RecordIdentifier`. There's a deprecation warning for `ActionController::RecordIdentifier`: "DEPRECATION WARNING: dom_id method will no longer be included by default in controllers since Rails 4.1. If you would like to use it in controllers, please include ActionView::RecordIdentifier module..."

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the answer to use your recommendation for Rails 4.

Answer (score 3):

What about doing this in a helper method?

**In spec/support/:**

```
module YourHelper
  def user_element(user, prefix = nil)
    '#' + dom_id(user, prefix)
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include YourHelper, :type => :request
  config.include ActionController::RecordIdentifier, :type => :request
end
```

Then you could write:

```
within user_element(user) do
  page.should have_content(@user.email)
end
```

Comment: not a good solution: you don't know how it's built and wouldn;t handle all particular cases, you should at least delegate to the Rails method, see my comment above

Comment: `dom_id` is an instance method on ActionController, but there isn't a controller instance readily available in this context (within Capybara tests). I'd be happy to use that method, but don't see an easy way to do so.

Comment: how do you think it's available in views?

Comment: I guess we could `config.include ActionController::RecordIdentifier`

Comment: `find("#user_#{@user.id}")` can be simplified to `"#user_#{@user.id}"`. [Capybara will invoke `find` automatically](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/session.rb#L221)

Comment: Updated to include both @apneadiving and Andrey Botalov's suggestions

Comment: `dom_id` creates `user_123`, not `#user_123`.

Comment: Ah, derp... I updated my answer to return `'#' + dom_id(user, prefix)`

Answer (score 2):

If you add something like this (to `spec/support/capybara_selectors.rb`, for example):

```
Capybara.add_selector(:active_record_object) do
  match { |value| value.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Base) }
  css {|record| 
    singleton_class.include ActionView::RecordIdentifier
    '#' + dom_id(record)
  }
end
```

Then you can use an even simpler and more intuitive syntax in your tests:

```
within user do
  find('button').click
end
```